# Alternatives for sp_getbindtoken/sp_bindsession

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions

According to the Microsoft docs [sp_getbindtoken](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180061.aspx)/[sp_bindsession](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174403.aspx) methods are deprecated. Is there any way to share a transaction between 2 different apps without using these methods?
I have some legacy code written in Delphi that starts a transaction and I would like to continue with this transaction within a C# written app.

Comment: I'm also stuck with this. The page redirects to MARS, but I'm not sending multiple active queries from the same application. I am starting a transaction in the stored procedure, then calling a web service using activex which needs to continue from the same session. It is sad that they haven't thought of this use case. In my opinion they simply can't "remove this feature in a future version" if there is no alternative and existing code depends on it.

Comment: Microsoft recomends using System.Transactions namespace; I'm still using sp_bindsession to share the same transaction with a client-server desktop application that calls a WCF Service. I've tried to use System.Transactions, but somethimes it requires MDAC as coordinator, too bad.